# Nest.JS with Multer and MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I am making a NestJS API where I want to make image uploads so that I can set the user profile photo or post banner

I am currently using mongodb for storage and the more recommended library to store images is Multer (what I got in my google searches)

I saw an Express tutorial so that I could see the way multer works...but when I tried to see the nestjs version...I only found examples that did not store it in the database...

So I need your help guys...can you please give me a CRUD nestjs with multer and mongodb code example or some links to help me please?

I appreciate if you have read this far

Answer (score 0):

The process of file uploading is quite simple. You can take a look at the official documentation [FIle Upload](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#file-upload). If you want a practical guide then this [Link](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/nestjs-file-uploading-using-multer/) maybe useful to you.
Regards!

Comment: Hi! Thanks SO MUCH for answering my question,and also thanks for the link,you really changed my mind!!! I was thinking about storing the file in the actual database,but after I saw the post and nest js official docs,I read some posts and saw that apparently it is better to store this kind of files in file system than in db,THANKS SO MUCH!!!! :) By the way,the GET file response can be used directly in src img tag property?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring too but if the response suits your use case, then maybe yes.